# TOC-like list where the entries come from an enumeration

Tags: table-of-contents, enumerate, links

I have a document divided in sections, with an enumeration inside every section, and each item having a highlighted title (similar in format to an encyclopedia).

> SECTION 1
>
> 1. **First title:** Explanation
> 2. **Second title:** Explanation
>
> SECTION 2
>
> 1. **First title:** Explanation
> 2. **Second title:** Explanation

What I'd like is to include, right below each section header, a kind of table of contents, a list with the titles of the items of that section's enumeration (but not their explanations) and hyperlinks to them. Of course, I want this to be done automatically.

> SECTION 1
>
> 1. First title [link1]
> 2. Second title [link2]
>
> ---
>
> 1. **First title:** [link1 links here] Explanation
> 2. **Second title:** [link2 links here] Explanation

Which is a good way to do this?

**EDITED:**

As required, I include some specific examples:

```
    \section{September 18}

%This would be the TOC-like list with a copy of the titles of the full enumeration below, with links to its corresponding entries

\begin{enumerate}
\item\textbf{Linear cones} %link1
\item\textbf{Partial order defined by a convex cone} %link2
\item\textbf{Dual cone} %link3
\end{enumerate}

\medskip
```

%Here we have the encyclopedia-like entries, linked frorm the previous TOC

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item\textbf{Linear cones:} Let $F$ be an ordered field and $V$ an $F$-vector space. A \emph{linear cone} $C$ is a subset of $V$ closed under positive scalar products. 
\item\textbf{Partial order defined by a convex cone:} If $C$ is a pointed salient convex cone, then the relation $x\leq y$ iff $y-x\in C$ is a partial order.
\item\textbf{Dual cone:} Let $S$ be any subset of a vector space $V$ over an ordered field. The \emph{dual cone} $S^*$ of $S$ is the convex cone
$$S^*:=\{v\in V \ | \ \la v,x\ra\geq0 \ \forall x\in S\}.$$
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: If you use `\subsection...` mark-up for your "titles" then `\usepackage{etoc}` and `\localtableofcontents`. You could also use `\paragraph`, but with a minimal example of your set-up, a comment is not adapted to provide extra explanations.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @jfbu The idea is that the enumeration titles should be easily readable, I don't want them to impair reading. For the moment being, they are just bolded sentences after the enumeration item and immediately before the explanation, like "1. **The eigenvalues of a matrix** [this is the title]: A matrix is an algebraic element....". Are you suggesting I should give more details? Which, exactly?

Comment: Please post a few such items we can copy paste.

Comment: If you don't use `\paragraph` anywhere else, I can provide easy solution using package `etoc`.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, I confirm I'm not using paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited due to problem with colons `:`. We don't want them in TOCs, hence this means a bit cumbersome mark-up. Also added global TOC to prove it is not contaminated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitemsinsection{%
  \begingroup
  \etocsetlevel{subsection}{6}% ignore real subsections
  \etocsetlevel{paragraph}{2}%  mimick paragraphs as subsections
  \etocsetnexttocdepth{paragraph}%
  \let\l@paragraph\l@subsection% mimick also in TOC. Stay in etoc
                               % "compatibility mode" so the class
                               % default is used
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Items in this section}%
  \localtableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{SECTION 1}

%\the\value{tocdepth}

\myitemsinsection

% colon is annoying here, it should not go to TOC.

\paragraph[First title]{First title:} Explanation

% or

\paragraph[Second title]{Second title:} Explanation

\subsection{Some subsection}

\section{SECTION 2}

\myitemsinsection

% Simply no colons ?
\paragraph{First title} Explanation

\paragraph{Second title} Explanation

\end{document}
```

[image]

The lists of items are hyperlinked (as normal TOC is hyperlinked in presence of hyperref).

---

A quite different approach, using `enumerate`.

**edited** to fix a problem with first compilation doing `\begin(enumerate}\end{enumerate}`. I initially thought adding `\etocchecksemptiness` would have solved this immediately, but see code comments for quote of etoc docs explaining why it failed. So we found a work-around.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\etocsetlevel{myitem}{6}% dummy sectioning level

\newcommand\mylistofitems{%
  \begingroup
  \etocsetlevel{subsection}{6}% ignore real subsections
  \etocsetlevel{myitem}{2}% 
  \etocsetnexttocdepth{myitem}%
  \etocsettocstyle{}{}%
  % to avoid problem on first compilation (missing \item), we do not insert
  % the \begin{enumerate} in \etocsettocstyle arguments,
  % but directly here.
  % 
  % Note: one could have hoped that putting it in \etocsettocstyle
  % and issueing \etocchecksemptiness would have worked. But alas,
  % the etoc doc says: 
  %    For a finalized document compiled with initially no
  %    auxiliary files, the first LaTeX run will declare all local
  %    TOCs non empty and print for each of them a heading (and no
  %    contents naturally).
  % This is bad here, because empty enumerate environment
  % raises LaTeX error.
  \etocsetstyle{myitem}
    {\begin{enumerate}}
    {}
    {\item\textbf{\etocname}}
    {\end{enumerate}}%
  \subsection*{Linked list of definitions}
    \localtableofcontents
  \hrule
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\newcommand\myitem[1]{\item\textbf{#1:}\etoctoccontentsline{myitem}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{SECTION 1}

\mylistofitems

\begin{enumerate}
% don't use colons at end of item titles here
\myitem{Linear cones} Let $F$ be an ordered field and $V$ an $F$-vector space. A \emph{linear cone} $C$ is a subset of $V$ closed under positive scalar products. 

\myitem{Partial order defined by a convex cone} If $C$ is a pointed salient convex cone, then the relation $x\leq y$ iff $y-x\in C$ is a partial order.

\myitem{Dual cone} Let $S$ be any subset of a vector space $V$ over an ordered field. The \emph{dual cone} $S^*$ of $S$ is the convex cone
$$S^*:=\{v\in V \ | \ \langle v,x\rangle\geq0 \ \forall x\in S\}.$$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Again the list of items is hyperlinked. It maybe closer to OP's expectations. It required a bit more work, as it goes via definition of a custom etoc toc line style.

When viewed in Acroread, the links are visible via red boxes:

[image]

Comment: If your document has no usage for `\paragraph` elsewhere this provides quick solution. Notice that by default the main TOC has tocdepth set to 3 in article class, so the main `\tableofcontents` will not display our mock-paragraphs. But you can add to preamble `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` to play it safe.

Comment: ah sorry, the paragraph titles should not include a colon `:`. I will fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to try it! Couldn't it be done so that we use the enumerate environment instead of the paragraph one?

Comment: Yes we can use enumerate. This is other type of solution, will add later.

Comment: @JoseBrox added enumerate based approach, possibly closer to what you asked in first place.

Comment: This is wonderful, you have saved me several ours of look and search. I cannot try it yet because there are currently problems with the Miktex repositories, and can't get etoc installed...

Comment: @JoseBrox ``\emph{linear cone} $C$ is a subset of $V$ closed under positive scalar products. `` appears mathematically dubious `:)`. You can download [`etoc.tds.zip`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/etoc.tds.zip) and after unzipping in some temp repertory, move `etoc.sty` to your project repertory.

Comment: I mean `positive scalar products` is clear enough but can be misinterpreted. What about  `product by positive scalars` instead?

Comment: I put the etoc.sty file on my localtexmf folder, but I cannot update the FNDB and hence WinEdt does not recognize the package (or so it seems, I'm no expert). The site miktex.org is currently down

Comment: Heh, you are right with the definition, but these are quick notes just for myself :-)

Comment: no issue with definition `:-)`. I mean you don't have to install `etoc.sty` in your `localtexmf`, just put it right there in same repertory as your `document.tex`.

Comment: but I know nothing about WinEdt...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83177/discussion-between-jose-brox-and-jfbu).